# English grammar

Tags: grammar

ple help me. Which one below is correct? any rules for this?

- Chinese cuisine
- China cuisine
- The cuisine of China

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3):

"Cuisine" does not allow a noun adjunct, so "China cuisine" is incorrect. However, "cuisine" can be used as either a count noun or a noncount noun. So "Chinese cuisine" and "the cuisine of China" are both correct.

In most cases, "Chinese cuisine" would be more idiomatic. But there are some exceptions where "the cuisine of China" is preferable:

> The cuisine of China is very different from that of India.

Comment: I agree with your answer in general, but I don't see what count or non-count has to do with it.  You can use either construction with either count or non-count nouns.

Comment: @stangdon If it were only a count noun, you would need "*the* Chinese cuisine."